# Можно ли задампить Expression'ы и Сериализаторы?

Tags: c#, .net

Сериализаторы и Expression'ы генерят сборки, которые хранятся в памяти.

Так вот, а можно ли как-нибудь получить их дампы и вскрыть через какой-нибудь декомпилятор, что бы посмотреть, как оно изнутри выглядит интереса ради?

Comment: Может, не совсем в тему, но авось будет интересно: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/formatters/binary/binaryformatter.cs.html и вот это: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/microsoft/scripting/Ast/Expression.cs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146877/how-do-i-get-an-il-bytearray-from-a-dynamicmethod

Comment: Для стандартного xml cериализатора можно указать чтобы сборка была внешним файлом. Начать изучение можно с [этого](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-serializer-generator-tool-sgen-exe).

Answer (score 1):

Вот интересная статья с кодом, обсуждающая преобразование деревьев выражений обратно во что-то, что напоминает (примерно) исходный код: [linq2codedom](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=linq2codedom) и вот есть еще либа с набором методов расширения для классов выражений Linq и DLR и набора визуализаторов отладчика для создания читаемых строковых версий деревьев выражений: [AgileObjects.ReadableExpressions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AgileObjects.ReadableExpressions), [ReadableExpressions.Visualizers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1232914.ReadableExpressionsVisualizers) и [MOAR Objects](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128000812/http://www.geekswithblogs.net/mrsteve/archive/2016/02/29/friendly-readable-expression-trees-debug-visualizer.aspx):